# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from : failed to load external entity

Tags: magento, soap, wsdl

We are getting the following error

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://www.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1' : failed to load external entity "https://www.example.com/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1"

What could possibly be the reason for this SOAP error?

Curlwrappers are already disabled.

As suggested, I checked out this post soap api : Start tag expected, '<' not found' I found that ini_set('display_errors',0); is already turned off. Still unable to overcome the SOAP error.

Answer (score 5):

1) Is your application directory password protected?

2) Try accessing like http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

3) Check php soap and xml rpc extensions are enabled or not.

Comment: Sure i'll check everything and drop you an update shortly. Thanks for the response and hope it mostly solves our issue.

Comment: I tried the step 2 but i got the same error. My application directory is not password protected. Is there any problem associated with this one. And how to check if my xml rpc extensions are enabled or not. I could not find a way to check this. Can you pl help me out with it. Thanks :)

Comment: run a file in root with echo phpinfo(). You should be able to see soap and xmlrpc enabled there

Comment: Hi Muk, xml rpc extensions are enabled for our site.

Comment: Has anyone got a solution for this

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue and I discovered that my provider had closed all server ports and restricted the access to only for some IP (I don't know if that is your case).
After security changes all works fine.

WaPoNe

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Can you pl let me know how can I find this out.

Comment: I've first tried to achieve WSDL via browser and it was accessible.
So, I've contacted my provider and we've checked the security policy on the specific port of firewall.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem upgrading to Magento 1.9.0.1. I solved the problem with [this official patch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes#ce19-patches-soap)

Comment: Hey Thanks but mine is Magento ver 1.5x. Has this version also got any patch to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I figured why I experienced this issue. Actually, that was a firewall issue. I did add correctly the rules to allow the secondary server to attack the magento's api but this one needs to reach out itself !
So after some headaches, I did just add a rule on the magento server's firewall to allow itself (the magento server) to reach its own api (kind of external lookup)...